# TFS Build - Powershell or custom activity?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I understand I can write my own custom activity (in C#) to execute custom logic during the build process. My understanding is that Powershell can also be used, but I am not sure where it fits in. I do understand Powershell is used for executing command line commands but how and where would I use it to customize the build process?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision whether to use Powershell or a Custom activity is for me based on who is responsible. If you have an activity that is created by the build master (for TFS) and therefor reusable for all the teams in the organization, I create a custom activity.

If the project team is responsible (for example a deployment script), the I use the powershell. I create an argument where the team can enter the path of the powershell script that needs to execute to deploy. The project team can optionally choose to enter a value in that argument. The project team can also maintain their powershell deployment script themselves without the help of the build master.

So in short:

- A reusable activity: Custom activity
- Activity for the team only: Powershell

Comment: So essentially, a powershell script is a substitute for custom activities and it appears that both of the serve the same purpose. Can I mix and match PS and activities? Can I invoke a PS script from custom activity?

Comment: In the custom activity you have access to all arguments and variables in the build. So it is not a substitute. You can use it mixed.

Comment: To invoke the PS script, the easiest way is to open the build process template and add a new argument to the build process template to pass the script you want. Add a convertWorkspace activity to convert the path from a Version controlled path to the local path. Then add a new InvokeProcess activity which executes Powershell with the argument "'@ <Argument>'".

Comment: See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx how to execute a powershell script from the Build Process Template

Answer (score 1):

For me, powershell is the way to go.  Here are my reasons why:

1. Script Independence:

You get script independence using this approach.  Example: I have a number of scripts that run after the build (i.e. the compile) process has completed:

- Instantiate Database
- Deploy Database Code
- Deploy Web Applications
- Verify Deployment
- Run Acceptance Tests

All of the above can be launched, debugged and tested independently without the need to queue a new build.

1. Powershell is easy to work with:

Custom assemblies tend to add a lot of complexity and flakiness to the solution.  Example: Upgrading from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 was very painful, because all of the Build Templates broke.  We had to recompile all of our custom assemblies, and only one dev on the team knew how TFS Build was set up to run our custom activities.  I have recently removed all custom assemblies from our build templates, and am using Powershell exclusively.

I have customised my process templates to call a user-defined powershell script after the TFS Build has completed.  I do this by using a paths argument in the build definition.  This argument is simply an array of strings pointing to the scripts.  I agree with Ewald, above, that TFS does not pass the build arguments to scripts.  To solve this, in my workflow template I parse each script in the string array, and replace well-known tokens with the build arguments - e.g. @(BuildNumber), @(SourcesDirectory) etc.  I find this to be a very easy and solid solution.